# How do I extract a year from a text string and return the year in another column?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of work orders in column A that contain a year. Below is a picture of some of the work orders in the list:

[image]

Goal: I would like to know how to create a function in VBA that extracts the year from the work orders in column A, and return the corresponding year in column B, like shown in the picture below:

[image]

I can enter the year manually by looking in column A, but I was wondering if there is a function that can do this task automatically.

Comment: You can use the `Right` formula, e.g `=VALUE(RIGHT(A1,4))`. Value will turn it into a number (which is all a date is), but you can do without.

Comment: Thank you! @SJR  This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: record a `text-to-columns` macro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using bellow is easiest than VBA macro.

Write below in cell `A1` and extend down to `A1` Address handled automatically.

```
=MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,3)+1 ,4)
```

Please note that `3` in above, is the first position after `_` character, So you can change to it to your needed situation or use  `FIND("_",A1)+1` instead of above `3`, as bellow:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("_",A1,FIND("_",A1)+1)+1 ,4)
```

Or bellow as a macro:

```
Sub ExtYear()
    Dim i, sh As Long
    sh = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To sh
        Cells(i, "B").Value = Split(Cells(i, "A").Value, "_")(UBound(Split(Cells(i, "A").Value, "_")))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Why would you use mid in this instance? It's quite obvious that errors will result, especially if you looked at the image that was provided where one of the strings was 1 character less than the remaining. `=RIGHT(A1, 4)` would have been the more appropriate answer.

Comment: Power of this two approach, (Using MID, or RIGHT) is dependent. I guide this two, because variety of answers.

Comment: I agree. Much better use of `Mid` than the original answer. Thanks for the revision

Comment: @MGae2M, please remove the dot from `.Cells`, or add a `with sheets ...` line